# How to setup a small website using docker

Tags: apache, docker

I have a question regarding Docker. That container's concept being totally new to me and I am sure that I haven't grasped how things work (Containers, Dockerfiles, ...) and how they could work, yet.

Let's say, that I would like to host small websites on the same VM that consist of Apache, PHP-FPM, MySQL and possibly Memcache.

This is what I had in mind:

1) One image that contains Apache, PHP, MySQL and Memcache
2) One or more images that contains my websites files

I must find a way to tell in my first image, in the apache, where are stored the websites folders for the hosted websites. Yet, I don't know if the first container can read files inside another container.

Anyone here did something similar?

Thank you

Comment: You were getting close votes because of the title, call for opinions are not liked on SO. Also in docker they are called containers normally not images.

Comment: @UsmanIsmail, thank you. Yeah I'm asking opinions and I doubt that I can rename that title.

Comment: I made an edit to the title, will show up when a moderator reviews it.

Comment: I would recommend you to check [fig](http://www.fig.sh/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

Your container setup should be:

1. MySQL Container
2. Memcached Container
3. Apache, PHP etc
4. Data Conatainer (Optional)

Run MySQL and expose its port using the -p command:

```
docker run -d --name mysql -p 3306:3306 dockerfile/mysql
```

Run Memcached

```
docker run -d --name memcached -p 11211:11211 borja/docker-memcached
```

Run Your web container and mount the web files from the host file system into the container. They will be available at `/container_fs/web_files/` inside the container. Link to the other containers to be able to communicate with them over tcp.

```
docker run -d --name web -p 80:80                  \ 
    -v /host_fs/web_files:/container_fs/web_files/ \ 
    --link mysql:mysql                             \
    --link memcached:memcached                     \
    your/docker-web-container
```

Inside your web container 
look for the environment variables `MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR` and `MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT` to tell you where to conect to the mysql instance and similarly `MEMCACHED_PORT_11211_TCP_ADDR` and `MEMCACHED_PORT_11211_TCP_PORT` to tell you where to connect to memcacheed.

Comment: And about Apache having multiple domains/websites attached to it. Should I keep the vhosts file outside of the Apache container?

Comment: If the domains never change you can bake the vhosts into the container and re-build container if they every change. However, its more standard to have vhosts either mounted in using volumes or generated using passed in environment variables or parameters passed into entrypoint

Comment: Is there a reason you used the dockerfile mysql image and not the official one?

Comment: @AdrianMouat There are a lot of comments under the official mysql repo which complain about problems. Also it does not expose the source dockerfile so its hard to debug when something goes wrong. I have used the dockerfile repo in the past, know that it comes up cleanly and has source available in case I need to debug anything. For someone new to docker I did not want to suggest a container that I have not tested and that does not have source exposed.

Comment: @UsmanIsmail All official images now link to their dockerfile and have for some time. I strongly suggest you use the official image unless there is a specific problem with it, but I understand not wanting to suggest something you hadn't tried.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way of using Docker is to try to keep to one process per container. So, Apache and MySQL etc should be in separate containers.

You can then create a data-container to hold your website files and simply mount the volume in the Webserver container using `--volumes-from`. For more information see https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/, specifically "Creating and mounting a Data Volume Container".

Comment: I thought that running all the "stacks" inside it's own container was a better way to "spawn" more websites in my VM.

Comment: @Cybrix, that's not the way it's normally done. It does mean you need some way of managing "clusters" of containers. The best way to do this is still being argued/developed.